# Semi Circular Progress bar Android - drawing semi circle

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I created a semi circular progress bar using this [devadvance\circularSeekBar](https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar)
and it looks like this when I select that custom view from the palette.

[image: progress bar in palette].

In this I have two Relative layouts with weights. Weight of the layout containing the progress bar is 2 and the bottom one has weight of 3. And layout width and height of the progress bar is set to wrap content.

So my issue is why does the progress bar look like this when selected from palette? Is it that the canvas size takes the perfect square? What I want is the semi circular progress bar to be fully enclosed by the layout like this.

[image: expected]

Any light on this is appreciated.

**EDIT** xml code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id ="@+id/calorie_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:clickable="true">
                <com.devadvance.circularseekbar.CircularSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/calorie_progressbar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:start_angle = "180"
                    app:end_angle = "0"
                    app:progress = "25"
                    app:circle_x_radius="200"
                    app:circle_y_radius="200"
                    app:circle_stroke_width = "30"
                    app:use_custom_radii="true"
                    app:circle_color ="#FFFACD"

                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/exercise_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/calorie_label"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/exercise_image" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#999"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It looks like you swapped the weight assignment (top = 3, bottom = 2). And probably you forgot to assign `android:layout_height="0dp"`, which is how the weights work. Also make sure that the root container is a LinearLayout (if it's a RelativeLayout, you can forget weights).

Comment: @DerGolem Root container is a LinearLayout. I've used `android:layout_height="match_parent"`
@MSGadag edited.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I couldn't imagine such a **high layout nesting level** (counter-productive). So, just replace `root` with `parent`

Comment: @DerGolem Can you refer me to a workaround for the high layout nesting? I'm new to Android.

Comment: At least (the immediate optimization that jumps in my eyes) the first relativeLayout can be safely removed. Then you can optimize further and remove the second one by adding the image to the TextView as a compoound drawable (and removing the ImageView, too). Move the weights to the CircularSeekBar and the TextView. Be sure to se the height of both to **0dp**, or weights **won't be applied**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is canvas height that you have. You have height for a circle and you draw half of circle on it.
 Try this:https://github.com/natasam/DemoProgressViewsLibApp
It has just what you need and you can easily customize **ArcProgressBar** to your needs. And height is height of arc, it is not the case of full circle like yours. You can also set padding, margins, width what you wish.

Comment: Better one than what I used!

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

insted of this

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for ur relative layout where you added weight property.

for

```
android:id="@+id/exercise_frame"   
android:id ="@+id/calorie_frame"
```

ids change **height="0dp"**

hope it works...

Comment: Nope. That didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't find the reason why it happens as shown but my guess is that it's supposed to work like that. Anyway I replaced it with this
[lzyzsd/CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) and it works pretty well enough for my use case.

Similar awesome stuff can be found here [android-arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/)