# android- I need to design 180 degree graph (half pie chart )

Tags: android, graph

I need to design half pie chart in Android, I have searched a lot but can't find any solution.
Any idea for a library to do that? Or can I make this manually?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I found the android-DecoView-charting library (link: https://github.com/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting) which is pretty good. It does have it's flaws though. If anyone has a better lib...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let`s think different ! Actually, we can say it is a custom progress bar. I never done anything like this before, but I would check the source code of the original progress bar. From this code, I could understand who they drawing the`filling effect` on Android. You need to apply the same code for the half pie bar!

http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java/?v=source

An older post from stackoverflow, I think it could be usefull for start:
[Semi Circular Progress bar Android - drawing semi circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796721/semi-circular-progress-bar-android-drawing-semi-circle)

Nice project to study how it drawing:
https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton?source=c

Comment: Did my answer helped ? If yes please accept as solution